# How to map a single java model object to two identical views in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to map a single java class to two identical views depends on the value of a field in this class:

here is my java class:

```
@Entity
@Immutable
@Table(name = "VIEW_ACCOUNT_PERMISSION")
public class AccountPermission implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column(name = "PERMISSION_ID")
private String id;

@Column(name = "ACCOUNT_ID")
private Long accountId;

@Column(name = "OBJECT_TYPE_ID")
@Type(type = "refObjectType")
private RefObjectType objectType;

// getters and setters
}
```

right now it mapped to just one view ("VIEW_ACCOUNT_PERMISSION"). Not to mention the OBJECT_TYPE_ID field can be 1,2 or 3.
Now I want to create another view the same as the "VIEW_ACCOUNT_PERMISSION" lets say "VIEW_ACCOUNT_PERMISSION2" which will have the records with OBJECT_TYPE_ID equals to 3 (1 and 2 will stay in the old view).

I can create another java model and map it to the new view but I don't like that. Is there any way to use single java model and then maps it (discriminate probably) to two views based on the value of objectType ?

Answer (score 0):

You can search on basis of entity names. One Hibernate pojo class can denote to multiple entity names with different tables.